# PostgreSQL dblink WHERE

Tags: postgresql

Подскажите, плз, если нужна условная выборка в запросе к внешней БД через dblink где правильно указывать where?
Сейчас запрос такого вида

select * from dblink('host=localhost port=000 user=000 password=000 dbname=000',
'select name, phone, order_id
FROM orders_details as d
where o.region in ('00001', '00002', '00003')
join orders o on d.order_id = o.order_id

') as q(...)

Сейчас получаю ошибку syntax error at or near "00001"

Comment: `(\'00001\', \'00002\', \'00003\')`

Comment: Спасибо, забыл про экранирование